# database migration tool like Flyway/Liquibase and ideas for Couchbase 7.x

Tags: database-migration, couchbase

How to approach schema/data migration when upgrading to Couchbase 7.x from Couchbase 5.x ?

By schema I mean indexes, that must be created before any document inserted,
so have to
create new collection,
define indexes,
move documents from older collection except for ref docs.

For SQL there is database migration tool like Flyway/Liquibase

P.S. I am not quite good with Couchbase.
Is there any other general practices to keep db/data in good shape in update in environments pipeline DEV->UAT->PREPROD->PROD ?

Answer (score 4):

There's a tool called [CouchVersion](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/CouchVersion).

> CouchVersion is a Java framework which helps you to manage changes in
> your Couchbase and synchronize them with your application. The concept
> is very similar to other db migration tools such as Liquibase or
> Flyway but without using XML/JSON/YML files.

Comment: It is not updated for couple of years though.

Comment: @PaulVerest I will push an update this week. But the framework itself is pretty straightforward and functional.

Answer (score 3):

All good points, just wanted to also add that there is a new liquibase connector released for Couchbase: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-couchbase

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use any 3rd party tool for this! Couchbase offers everything out of the box.

First some background knowledge, couchbase is designed to work in a cluster that consists of at least two nodes, ideally in production you should use at least 3 nodes. Given that, if you want to upgrade couchbase you can do that **live** on the cluster! You simply remove a node from the cluster, upgrade the node, then joint it back into the cluster, that's it! The cluster continues to work while you remove and upgrade it node by node. **Nothing is lost, no downtime, your clients will not even feel it.**

Second, you can upgrade a couchbase cluster node only from one major version to the next (+1) major version, so in your case you have to upgrade all nodes from major version 5.x to 6.x then when all nodes in the cluster have version 6.x you upgrade all nodes from 6.x to 7.x

Note that couchbase cluster can run different node versions in the same cluster (called mixed mode), only when all nodes are upgraded to the latest version only then all version features are available.

I personally upgraded couchbase in test and production from version 6.0.3 to 6.5, from 6.5 to 6.6 and from 6.6 to 7.1

Comment: We have already upgraded couchbase nodes from 6.x to 7.x
We now need to upgrade  schema, use bucket.scope.collection naming and move data into specific collection. And was the question....

But we cannot upgrade client versionuse Couch

Comment: Awarding bounty, as there were no newer answers

Answer (score -1):

There is also data migration tool
https://github.com/tchlyah/couchmove

But specifically our current top option is to use solution provided by own CI/CD team
(that similarly defines SQL++ statements to execute)